# Drupal messages are not appearing on code loaded user login form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am inserting a user login form in my template using drupal_get_form('user_login') and drupal_render_children the form is showing fine however there is a problem in messages. If, for example, the user submitted an empty form messages should display saying that you should type your username and password, this is not happening. However if I refreshed the page the messages appear! Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of handling the form validation on client side using javascript instead? You can include a javascript file from your hook_init() or hook_preprocess_page() using drupal_add_js() function. I ran into this issue too a while back. I have had to refresh the page to see the message triggered by drupal_set_message(). I ended up going the javascript way.

Comment: javascript validation will work fine however I should do the validation on the server side.